# Long string pagination done right

Tags: javascript, regex, string, text

I want to split a long text into smaller chunks, that will act as pages.

```
    var longText = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
            var page = longText.substring(i*100,(i+1)*100);
            document.write(page + "<br /><hr />");
    }
```

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zrE4n/) on jsfiddle.

This code splits the text, but in a stupid way, cutting also words in half.
It would be far better, for example, creating substrings ending at the last space in a certain number of characters (count 100 characters, then go back to the last space).
How would you achieve it?

[Second shot](http://jsfiddle.net/8uNdh/)
[Third shot](http://jsfiddle.net/8uNdh/1/)

Comment: I don't know Javascript, but maybe this page can help you: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html -- basically, you can cycle through the input with a RegExp object and check for its lastIndex property: if you cycle through the input with `/\w+\s+/, and lastIndex (close to) a multiple of 100, you have a substring.

Comment: Yes, I suspected that RegExp could help here (that's why I added the tag, +1 for you :D). But I don't know them enough to use them to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those looking for a working answer:

```
<div id="long-text">Lorem ipsum [...]</div>


    <script>
var splitter = function(id) {
var longText = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;

var pageLenght = 200;
var charsDone = 0;
var htmlBefore = "<p>";
var htmlAfter = "</p>";

while (charsDone <= longText.length && (pageLenght+charsDone)<longText.length) {
    var pageBox = longText.substr(lastSpace,pageLenght);
    var lastSpace = charsDone + pageBox.lastIndexOf(" ");
    var page = longText.substring(charsDone,lastSpace);
    document.write(htmlBefore + page  + htmlAfter);
    charsDone = lastSpace;
    }

    document.write(longText.substr(lastSpace,pageLenght));
}


splitter("#long-text");
```

You can easily use arrays instead of writing to document.
You will also want to set your html to your needs, do it in htmlBefore and htmlAfter.
See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/asNhn/).

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
function paginate(longText, pageSize) {
  var parts = longText.split(/[ \n\t]/g);
  if (parts.length == 0)
    return [];
  var pages = [parts.unshift()];
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 1) {
    var part = parts[i];
    if (part.length + pages[pages.length - 1].length < pageSize) {
      pages[pages.length - 1] += " " + part;
    } else {
      pages.push(part);
    }
  }
  return parts;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, please?

Comment: Sorry, edited to include the complete algorithm. Please let me know if this isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks David. I made a fiddle but didn't make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/5VMLz/

Comment: Sorry David! Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/2FGPS/ . How do I use your code snippet?

Comment: Might also want to put in a check for long, long words that should also be broken.  Rare, but it could happen.  (The actual solution to this problem is to port a TeX renderer to javascript :P )

Comment: So, a couple of bugs in my code aside (I should have made it clear that it was just an example)… What don't you understand? From your fiddle, it looks like you're trying to `document.write` an array… Which doesn't really make sense. Is this because you don't really understand my code? Or because you don't really understand JavaScript?

Comment: David, I'm tired and your code isn't working. However I found a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/apCeH/

Comment: @David Wolever My code (see other answer) is working just fine, but since you made the effort I wish to give you the chance to fix yours so I can accept your answer. I fiddled it with again, with a clearer output http://jsfiddle.net/ftdQz/ .